# Magento : Mass Uploading Qty by sku - Become Out of Stock - 2

Tags: product, stock-status, magento-1.9.3.2, qty

mass uploading qty by sku but need to change code to "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock - 2" as thats what we have set global.

```
public function _updateStocks($data){
    $connection     = $this->_getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newQty         = $data[1];
    $productId      = $this->_getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = $this->_getAttributeId();

    $sql            = "UPDATE " . $this->_getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
            " . $this->_getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
            SET
            csi.qty = ?,
            csi.is_in_stock = ?,
            css.qty = ?,
            css.stock_status = ?
            WHERE
            csi.product_id = ?
            AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
            $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $productId));
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that you want to upload new QTY via excel sheet in magento.
Make an excel sheet with "sku" heading in "colA", "qty" in "colB" and "is_in_stock" in "colC"
qty is number field and is_in_stock is 0 or 1 (true false) field.

[image]

Once done, import via export/import or Dataflow Profiles. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

easy fix in the end.

```
$isInStock      = $newQty > 2 ? 1 : 0;
$stockStatus    = $newQty > 2 ? 1 : 0;
```